# Selecting different code branches when using a shared base image in Docker

Tags: jenkins, docker, continuous-integration

I am containerising a codebase that serves multiple applications. I have created three images;

`app-base`:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get install package

COPY ./app-code /code-dir

...
```

`app-foo`:

```
FROM app-base:latest

RUN foo-specific-setup.sh
```

and `app-buzz` which is very similar to `app-foo`.

This works currently, except I want to be able to build versions of `app-foo` and `app-buzz` for specific code branches and versions. It's easy to do that for `app-base` and tag appropriately, but `app-foo` and `app-buzz` can't dynamically select that tag, they are always pinned to `app-base:latest`.

Ultimately I want this build process automated by Jenkins. I could just dynamically re-write the Dockerfile, or not have three images and just have two nearly-but-not-quite identical Dockerfiles for each app that would need to be kept in sync manually (later increasing to 4 or 5). Each of those solutions has obvious drawbacks however.

I've seen lots of discussions in the past about things such as an `INCLUDE` statement, or dynamic tags. None seemed to come to anything.

Does anyone have a working, clean(ish) solution to this problem? As long as it means Dockerfile code can be shared across images, I'd be happy. If it also means that the shared layers of images don't need to be rebuilt for each app, then even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still use build args to do this.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG APP_NAME
RUN echo $APP_NAME-specific-setup.sh >> /root/test
ENTRYPOINT cat /root/test
```

Build:

```
docker build --build-arg APP_NAME=foo -t foo .
```

Run:

```
$ docker run --rm foo
foo-specific-setup.sh
```

In your case you could run the correct script in the RUN using the argument you just set before. You would have one Dockerfile per app-base variant and run the correct set-up based on the build argument.

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get install package

COPY ./app-code /code-dir
ARG APP_NAME
RUN $APP_NAME-specific-setup.sh
```

Any layers before setting the ARG would not need to be rebuilt when creating other versions.

You can then push the built images to separate docker repositories for each app.

If your apps need different `ENTRYPOINT` instructions, you can have an `APP_NAME-entrypoint.sh` per app and rename it to `entrypoint.sh` within your `APP_NAME-specific-setup.sh` (or pass it through as an argument to `run`).

Comment: This solution works, but not quite how you said. If I do the above and keep one Dockerfile per `app-base` variant, then I would just have the same issue of those variants being hard coded to a single version of the base image (unless I have misunderstood). Your solution actually goes one better than that though, in that it means I can remove the need for multiple Dockerfiles altogether. Could you let me know if I have understood correctly?

Comment: Yes, you need only one Dockerfile per base image and you can use the argument to run the specific script you want for each app. If you can parameterize further you can even create all of the base images in a single dockerfile by using more build arguments, but it depends on your specific problem if that is a sensible idea. If you want to make the FROM field dynamic you would have  to expand the variable before sending the Dockerfile to the daemon. If the only changes from app-base to app-base are for instance Ubuntu version, this might make sense.

Comment: I've added a couple of bits of info about `ENTRYPOINT` and pushing the images to separate repositories. I'd prefer to not have to hide so much info from the Dockerfile in a bash script, but this looks like the best solution that the current Dockerfile syntax allows. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Good edit! Although you can actually use the build argument when setting the entrypoint, so you don't actually need to rename the script anywhere, I included this instead of the renaming.

Comment: Ah, I'm afraid not. `ENTRYPOINT` ignores `ARG` values. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18492

Comment: Sorry, you can do ENV APP_NAME=$APP_NAME to export the build arg to an environment variable. But that might be less pretty than just renaming the script.

Comment: Yeah, saw that. Perhaps keep the original renaming option in the answer and add the ENV export in as an edit too?